# Additional columns added to saved CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have following code which generate features from csv

```
def gen_features_per_id(file_name, label):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter=',')
    df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], unit='s')

    row = []
    column_names = ['group_timestamp', 'label',
                        'x_mean', 'x_median', 'x_stdev', 'x_raw_min', 'x_raw_max', 'x_abs_min', 'x_abs_max',
                        'y_mean', 'y_median', 'y_stdev', 'y_raw_min', 'y_raw_max', 'y_abs_min', 'y_abs_max',
                        'z_mean', 'z_median', 'z_stdev', 'z_raw_min', 'z_raw_max', 'z_abs_min', 'z_abs_max' ]

    group_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

    for group_name, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10s', key='dt')):
        print(f'Start time {group_name} has {len(g)} records within 10 secs')

        group_timestamp = group_name
        label = label

        x = g['x'].head(50)
        x_mean = x.mean()
        x_median = x.median()
        x_std_dev = statistics.stdev(x)
        x_raw_min = min(x)
        x_raw_max = max(x)
        x_abs_min = min(abs(x))
        x_abs_max = max(abs(x))

        # print(
        #     f'Mean : {x_mean}, Median : {x_median}, Stdev : {x_std_dev}, '
        #     f'X raw Min : {x_raw_min}, X raw Max : {x_raw_max}, '
        #     f'X abs Min : {x_abs_min}, X abs Max : {x_abs_max}'
        # )

        y = g['y'].head(50)
        y_mean = y.mean()
        y_median = y.median()
        y_std_dev = statistics.stdev(y)
        y_raw_min = min(y)
        y_raw_max = max(y)
        y_abs_min = min(abs(y))
        y_abs_max = max(abs(y))

        # print(
        #     f'Mean : {y_mean}, Median : {y_median}, Std dev : {y_std_dev}, '
        #     f'X raw Min : {y_raw_min}, X raw Max : {y_raw_max}, '
        #     f'X abs Min : {y_abs_min}, X abs Max : {y_abs_max}'
        # )

        z = g['z'].head(50)
        z_mean = z.mean()
        z_median = z.median()
        z_std_dev = statistics.stdev(z)
        z_raw_min = min(z)
        z_raw_max = max(z)
        z_abs_min = min(abs(z))
        z_abs_max = max(abs(z))

        # print(
        #     f'Mean : {z_mean}, Median : {z_median}, Std dev : {z_std_dev}, '
        #     f'X raw Min : {z_raw_min}, X raw Max : {z_raw_max}, '
        #     f'X abs Min : {z_abs_min}, X abs Max : {z_abs_max}'
        # )
        row.append(group_timestamp)
        row.append(label)

        row.append(x_mean)
        row.append(x_median)
        row.append(x_std_dev)
        row.append(x_raw_min)
        row.append(x_raw_max)
        row.append(x_abs_min)
        row.append(x_abs_max)

        row.append(y_mean)
        row.append(y_median)
        row.append(y_std_dev)
        row.append(y_raw_min)
        row.append(y_raw_max)
        row.append(y_abs_min)
        row.append(y_abs_max)

        row.append(z_mean)
        row.append(z_median)
        row.append(z_std_dev)
        row.append(z_raw_min)
        row.append(z_raw_max)
        row.append(z_abs_min)
        row.append(z_abs_max)


        group_df = group_df.append([row], ignore_index=True)
        group_df.to_csv("some.csv", index=False)
        row = []
```

But saved csv file have additional columns added to the start of the csv header which is equal to supplied number of columns

**Sample CSV**

```
datetime,x,y,z,label
1493740845,0.0004,-0.0001,0.0045,bad
1493740846,0.0003,0.0002,0.0047,bad
1493740847,0.0005,0.0001,0.0049,bad
1493740848,0.0006,0.0004,0.005,bad
1493740849,0.0006,-0.0003,0.005,bad
1493740851,0.0001,-0.0003,0.0039,bad
1493740852,-0.0006,0.0003,0.0046,bad
B1493740853,0.0001,0.0,0.0048,bad
```

**Output:**

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,group_timestamp,label,x_abs_max,x_abs_min,x_mean,x_median,x_raw_max,x_raw_min,x_stdev,y_abs_max,y_abs_min,y_mean,y_median,y_raw_max,y_raw_min,y_stdev,z_abs_max,z_abs_min,z_mean,z_median,z_raw_max,z_raw_min,z_stdev
# data ... ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
# data ... ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

How to fix this?

---

Additionally : If you can help me to simplify the code more.

Comment: can you give one row of sample data so we could execute the code

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal sample csv input added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem for each loop in `groupby` is necessary append values to `row` list and then append to `rows` outside loop for nested lists, so possible pass to `DataFrame` cosntructor in last step:

```
#added for nested lists (outside loops)
rows = []

df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], unit='s')

for group_name, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10s', key='dt')):
        #added for row per loop
        row = []
        print(f'Start time {group_name} has {len(g)} records within 10 secs')

        group_timestamp = group_name
        label = label 

        x = g['x'].head(50)
        x_mean = x.mean()
        ....
        row.append(z_abs_max)

        rows.append(row)

#DataFrame outside loops
group_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)
print (group_df)
```

Your solution should be improved by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
#custom aggregate functions
def std_dev(x):
    return statistics.stdev(x)

def abs_min(x): 
    return x.abs().min()

def abs_max(x): 
    return x.abs().max()

d = ['mean','median',std_dev, 'min','max', abs_min, abs_max]
cols = ['x','y','z']

#filtered first 50 rows
df[cols] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10s', key='dt'))[cols].head(50)

#aggregate functions
group_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10s', key='dt'))[cols].agg(d)
group_df.columns = group_df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (group_df)
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I wonder what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: I suppose dataframe inside the loop causing the issue

Comment: @user158 - there is appended still values to row variable, so for eah loop was added new 23 values, so in secon din loop is 46, then 46+23...

Comment: but row is emptied at the end of each iteration, only column row is affected not data rows

Comment: @user158 - hmmm, I miss it. Reason for columns with `1,2,3` is `group_df = group_df.append([row], ignore_index=True)` - There is added Series with `0,1,2` index and create new columns. So should be changed to `group_df = group_df.append(pd.Series(row, index=column_names), ignore_index=True)` for prevent it

Comment: thanks that explain things, better to add it to the answer too

Comment: @user158 - Working for better solution ;)

Comment: Thats  better. while that remove iteration and manual column names how could I insert `group_timestamp` and `label` and how it calculate min, max, mean, median, do I need functions for them too

Comment: @user158 - I think `group_timestamp ` should be in `DatetimeIndex`, so after my solution should working `group_df = group_df.reset_index()` and for label use `group_df.insert(0, 'label', label)` after solution

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. mean, median, min, max calculation looks like magic to me here, how is that happening without any functions?